# How to call C++ exe with multiple parameters from command line using C# .net

Tags: c#, c++, vtk

i am performing offline operations on images taking image as a input  with parameters and processing it in VTK C++ exe i am unable to pass parameters to C++ exe through C#  program and retrive output .
please explain  me with  some example

Comment: It should be the same way as any executable. Why do you ask specifically about a C++ executable? Once you have an executable, it doesn't matter which language it was made with, they all behave the same

Comment: The thing which confused me first is that DOS/Windows programs get only *one* string as parameter. The OS/C++ runtime parses the string and presents it to `main` as the `argv` array of strings. Argument splitting is simply by whitespace; double quotes prevent splitting. So if you have multiple parameters, you concatenate them with a space inbetween, possibly surrounding each one with double quotes.

Comment: Define "output" in this case. What is your output? Where/how does it get outputted? How are you trying to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you just mean that you have a compiled C++ program (which we'll call "foo.exe", with path stored in string "exe_folder") and you want to call that with command line parameters (stored in string "exe_params") from C#, then the following should work:

```
string exe_params = "target_image.jpeg HOUGH_TRANSFORM"; // Or whatever params are appropriate.
string exe_full_path = Path.Combine(exe_folder, "foo.exe");
Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exe_full_path, exe_params);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Devid,I have tried your code of snippet and it was successfully working but it was only invoking exe without understanding my exe_params.

Comment: My exe param is one image file which is in same exe_folder. But unable to invoke that image file.

Comment: Just a guess, but if the parameter that "isn't working" is a filename, then perhaps the problem is that the new process is being run from the working folder of the C# program rather than the folder that the .exe program is stored in, and so it can't find the file specified in the parameter.

You could test this by passing a ProcessStartInfo object to Process.Start, instead of path and parameter strings, and explicitly specifying the desired working directory in the ProcessStartInfo object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Let say that your executable is called test.exe and it is in the test dir. For me, the following would be working:

```
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C cd C:\\..test\\ && test.exe target_image.jpg yourtransformation";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

If you have further problems, try setting the [working directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) of processStartInfo.